# Took a picture of my laptop screen with my iPhone. The yellowish pattern in the image look like magnetic lines. How is this possible?

Tags: magnetic-fields, imaging

The pattern seems consistent with the magnetic force lines of a bar magnet.
[image]

Comment: Was your camera flash on? Also, can you check if the same pattern appears if you take a picture of a piece of paper or some low light/contrast thing?

Comment: No, the flash was off and other images look fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That looks like a [Moire pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern) to me.  You have a camera with a grid of pixels on the imaging element and a screen with a grid of (colored) pixels.  These elements don't line up exactly, so you get the odd patterns.

Try taking another image with the camera slightly twisted along the lens axis or slightly angle the lens axis to the laptop.  If it's a Moire, then the image will look quite different in both cases.

> And if I am understanding it right, these type of Moire patterns are
>   made as a result of overlapping of curved grid lines

No, they're similar to aliasing effects.  Imagine taking a picture of a grid.  The optics will put a picture of the grid onto the imaging sensor (CCD).  At some distance/zoom, the lines of the grid will be almost exactly the same distance apart as the CCD elements.  If the lines fall between the elements, they won't be seen easily.  If they fall exactly on the elements, they are seen easily.

But your laptop screen isn't all the same distance from the lens.  It's flat, so the edges are farther than the center is.  This means the angular separation of the LCD pixels changes from the center to the edge.  This apparent change in the grid separation from one part of the image to another makes the bright/dark/bright/dark areas appear.  They're curved because the apparent grid size changes with distance (so you get sort of circular patterns).

Your original image looks to me to be a very lucky shot.  The grid in the middle is free of much distortion over a large area.  Pretty neat.

Comment: being trying it for some time now. Cant seem to reproduce the effect.
And if I am understanding it right, these type of Moire patterns are made as a result of overlapping of curved grid lines ?

Comment: I would try to turn on the (digital) viewfinder and while looking at it move the camera to different distances.  I would expect there to be certain distances where the screen showed odd patterns.

Comment: http://imgur.com/MNPNdD0 This looks more like it. It seems it was just coincidence that the original pattern resembled magnetic force fields.