# Is the pattern shown in the background due to YDSE or something else?

Tags: optics, waves, interference, double-slit-experiment

This a photo of a image from a phone camera , we can see that there is a fringe pattern is showing up i want to know is it due to camera being acting as a double slit source or something else ? As this pattern i never read in theory.(Ignore whats written above the background) [image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moiré_pattern

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/417927/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/183481/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Thanks @Qmechanic my doubt is cleared , what should i do should i delete it or just leave it and you will make this as duplicate ?

Comment: Thanks @rob too