# What causes the curvy line to exist?

Tags: optics, everyday-life

Excuse me, but I am wondering what optical phenomena causes the curvy line to exist on the iron fence?

[image]

Comment: [Moiré pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9G9pNFVUfg)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/417927/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/183481/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is a Moire pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern).